# How to return data from ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my front end JavaScript application, I make an ajax request to fetch data from the server. As soon as I get the data, I want to return that piece of information to the view.

```
var view_data;
$.ajax({
    url:"/getDataFromServer.json",
    //async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(response_data_json) {
        view_data = response_data_json.view_data;
        console.log(view_data); //Shows the correct piece of information
        return view_data; // Does not work. Returns empty data
    }
 });

 // return view_data; --> Keeping the return outside of the ajax call works but then I need to make my ajax call synchronous in order for this return clause to be executed after the ajax call fetches data.
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You should add the jquery tag to your post..

Comment: you are assigning `view_data = response_data_json.view_data;` so why are you not using `view_data` why are you returning it in success method.

Comment: may be this can help you http://codingbin.com/get-return-data-ajax-call/

Comment: i solved this problem by writting out the data into a cookie to then use it in another function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of returning `data` from `success`: pass `data` to a function.

```
var view_data;
$.ajax({
    url:"/getDataFromServer.json",
    //async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(response_data_json) {
        view_data = response_data_json.view_data;
        console.log(view_data); //Shows the correct piece of information
        doWork(view_data); // Pass data to a function
    }
 });

function doWork(data)
{
    //perform work here
}
```

Comment: But, How can I use doWork function and get return data into another change event.

Answer (score 7):

ajax is by nature asyc. The code doesn't wait for the response from your `success` callback, so the data isn't accessible outside of `success` unless passed.

You'd need to handle the data inside the success, try calling a separate method/function:

```
function handleResponse(data) {
    // do something with data
}

success:function(response_data_json) {
    handleResponse(response_data_json.view_data); 
}
```

here are the docs on jquery's [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You could also just use an external success function rather then an annon inline that then calls the function anyway. it will still pass the data as a param

```
function handleResponse(data) {
  // do something
}

$.ajax({
    url:"/getDataFromServer.json",
    //async: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success:handleResponse
 });
```

UPDATE: as pointed out in the comments, you might be better using a `http get` request rather then a `post`. they [both have advantages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) however `get` requests can be cached, so for retrieving data it might give a perf boost.

Comment: Am I incorrect in assuming that because he wants to fetch data from the server it should be a ```GET``` request, as opposed to a ```POST``` request?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald no necessarily, although in this case it appears so. If he was posting data and wanted to handle a fail/success message from the back end then a post make sense, but in this I think you're right, it should be a `get`

Answer (score 1):

that's the best way to pass prams and get response

```
function get_table_data_helper(table, id){
    return $.ajax({
        url: DOCUMENT_ROOT + '/php/get_table_data.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {table: table, id: id},
        async: false,
        success:function(add_clint_res){
            (jQuery.parseJSON(add_clint_res));
        }
    });
}
function get_table_data(table, id, column){
    return jQuery.parseJSON(get_table_data_helper(table, id).success(function (data) {  return jQuery.parseJSON(data);  })['responseText'])[column];

}
```

then do get your data like

```
get_table_data('city_table', '3', 'city_col')
```